# Having trouble with --out cucumber

Tags: cucumber

I'm currently investigating using cucumber's --out option to write my test results out to a file. However, I'm running into some difficulties, and can't find a lot of useful information about it online. I created a reports folder under my features folder, and put a file text.html in it, so it looks like this:

```
features
       -> reports
               -> test.html
```

However, when I run

```
cucumber --tags @test --format html --out reports/test.html
```

I get the error

```
Not a directory @ rb_sysopen - reports/test.html
Error creating formatter: html (Errno::ENOTDIR)
```

If I just run

```
cucumber --tags @test --format html --out reports
```

The test doesn't complain and goes and does its thing, but I can't find any report in reports. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the output folder is relative to the project root, not the `features` directory, so your directory structure should look like this:

```
features
reports
    -> test.html
```

Move your `reports` directory into the project root and then you should see output being created.

Comment: Cool, that worked for me. Do you know what file type I should be making if I'm using the pretty format though? Is pretty a file type supported by out?

Comment: @Keenan pretty is the default pure text output you see when you run on the command line. You could output it to a file, but normally you wouldn't as its designed to view realtime in the terminal. Other formats like html or json are commonly used for offline reporting.

Comment: Got it, I'll stick to html then. Thanks